# Sword of Truth: Gradual style shift?

Tags: politics, the-sword-of-truth

I really enjoyed the Sword of Truth series by Terry Goodkind.  One of the things that I found somewhat fascinating about it is that there seems to be a gradual shift as you read the books from a classic, 'country boy finds out he is destined for greatness and can do magic and must kill the evil guy' story to a more complex, politically fraught story about the human condition.  It did, in fact, start to sound more like an Ayn Rand story with a little magic thrown in than another Tolkien-esque saga.

So my questions:

1. Is that shift intentional?  Did the author really intend that, or is it just my perception?
2. If it is true, has any other author written a series of books with such a clear thematic shift? 
   *(Note that I'm looking for a yes or no for this question, not a list of other examples.  My reason for asking is that in all my reading, I don't recall coming across something like this before, so I wonder about its uniqueness.)*

Comment: Your second question will be very hard to answer without a 'list of works', you may want to consider changing it.

Comment: 2. <ahem> *Harry Potter* is the most famous example, and of course it's hardly the only other one.

Comment: @Gilles - I haven't read the harry potter novels, I'm waiting until I've seen all the movies since that's where I started.  Don't want to ruin the movies, since the book is always better!  That being said, I'm not seeing a real clear thematic shift there, just a shift in maturity mirroring the main characters.

Comment: With regard to your second point:theme shifts seem to take place in most of the books I read (though not always political in nature). Could be because writers mature after one or two books, or with popularity comes the license to experiment out of the standard conventions.

Comment: His preaching on Randian themes definitely gets more frequent and increasingly hyperbolic as the series goes on.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Yes. Goodkind has said in many interviews that the whole series is intended to be a reflection of his own political beliefs (Randian Objectivism). He (in)famously said that he writes novels not fantasy.
2. Oh yes. First thing that pops up in my mind is Heinlein's Starship Troopers. On the outside it looks like run of the mill military SciFi, but is in fact the author displaying his political views on the role of the military in society. Another one is Philip Pullman's "His Dark Materials" books. They start out as a typical YA fantasy adventure (feisty little girl searching for her kidnapped friend in a fantasy steam punk-ish world), and slowly becomes the author's very thinly disguised rant against organized religion in general and the Catholic church in particular.

Comment: And your response to 1 is why I really don't listen to what he says, and don't read past book 6 any longer...sure, it's not 'fantasy'...it just happens to have dragons, magic, wizards, faries, demons, specters, dominatrices, an evil empire, mcGuffins, sorceresses, and hosts of other fantastic elements.  Not fantasy in the slightest.

Comment: I'm the same as you Jeff. I couldn't stomach it beyond book 5. Then again, the political views it holds are opposite to mine and as they say YMMV.

Comment: @Jeff - that's hilarious, I had no idea he said that.  I think authors in general need to get over the resistance to genre classification in an attempt to be regarded as a literary writer.  However, I rarely pay attention to what authors say unless it's specifically in reference to the story they wrote.  There are, of course, exceptions, but those are for exceptional authors :)

Comment: @morganpdx - Yeah. That particular comment has fueled more than one flame war between fantasy lovers and die hard Goodkind fans.

Comment: @SystemDown: I think the flame war is partly fuelled by the fact that he writes *pretty good* fantasy, but *extremely badly written* Randian political story.  Being able to focus on one or the other completely changes the quality of the story.

Comment: Hm, for Starship Troopers I think you must watch the movie and avoid the book for the said military feeling.

Comment: @BalogPal - Not really. The movie is a nice action flick but it fails as a military film. No armor? No air cover? Have you guys ever heard of tactics?

Comment: @BalogPal - no, I disagree.  If you pay attention to the high school social studies class discussions and the classroom talk in the military academy, that tone comes through loud and clear in the books, even to the concept on only those having done military service getting the right to vote.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes.  Yes, it very much was.
2. Not that I'm aware of, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: I'm not changing my answer, as both Gilles in the question's comments and System Down in another answer have provided good responses, but my reading of the 2nd question (likely an incorrect reading) indicated that morgan wanted to know if there were other series that shifted towards randian themes, not just ones that suffered a thematic shift.  As I said, I'm likely wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a thematic shift, not a specific Randian one.

Comment: ...and I'll update my answer to reflect that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is as much of a shift as it is a progression of themes. The typical "underdog boy fights seemingly unbeatable evil" theme remains a constant throughout the entire series. I think the focus of the books comes from the Wizard's Rules introduced in them.

The first book is all about seeking the truth. The first pages of the book embrace this theme when Richard is investigating the death of his father. Even when Richard receives the Sword of Truth, he is told that the sword is just a tool and he is the real weapon. This concept is reinforced repeatedly throughout the series. In fact, many of the fantasy elements of the series, such as magic, are repeatedly canceled out or balanced. We never get the full satisfaction of some wizard or sorceress utterly destroying the other side with magic. Both sides are constantly nullifying each other's efforts. I believe this directs the focus to the more moral and philosophical themes of the stories.

You can also tie some of the later themes of the series back to the first book. For example the Wizard's Fourth Rule is displayed when Richard kills Denna. You will also find many characters throughout the series (good and evil) breaking various Wizard's Rules and having to deal with the consequences.

In response to the books being novels, not fantasy; I think the following quote from Terry Gookind explains the point of view rather well.

> I've always said fantasy is sort of "stealth philosophy." It allows you to say things that sound very dramatic and get away with it. If you had characters in modern fiction say the same things as they're driving down the street in an Oldsmobile they'd sound ludicrous! Fantasy allows you to bend the world and the situation to more clearly focus on the moral aspects of what's happening. In fantasy you can distill life down to the essence of your story.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my take is that the idea of whole world was born more like after the first book. And matured much on the way.

The Chainfire cycle, however genial it is, does not look like was in Terry's head at writing the First Rule. (what IMO makes it even more an accomplishment.)

Tweeking the past a bit is quite common (say, anyone really believes he made TNH the way it was already aiming the trilogy? ;).

Note that statement form the interview in SD's answer is not really a contradiction, and SOT certainly does reflect Terry's views, only I don't think the events and the arc was anywhere planned ahead. So my answer to the original question on the shift is a *real* yes. (SD's answer would really make it a no -- there's no shift we go along the same idea along the way, right? ;)

The second part is hard to answer. On this scale and level of focusing and coherence I'd say no. But expression of a set of ideas do happen and you can see them recurring, not only in sequels but loosely coupled or "unrelated" works. Say you read all of Heinlein, how many core ideas say hello?